# c++ std::string array as function parameter

Tags: c++, string, reference, tokenize

I'm kind of new to C++. I want to make split function for std::string in c++ like java split function in String class(I don't want to use boost library). so I made custom split function which is..

```
using namespace std;

void ofApp::split(string ori, string tokens[], string deli){
    // calculate the number of tokens
    int length = 0;
    int curPos = 0;

    do{
        curPos = ori.find(deli, curPos) + 1;
        length++;
    }while(ori.find(deli, curPos) != string::npos);
    length++;

    // to save tokens, initialize tokens array
    tokens = new string[length];   // this is the line I'm suspicious about..

    int startPos = 0;
    int strLength = 0;
    int curIndex = 0;
    do{
        strLength = ori.find(deli, startPos) - startPos;
        tokens[curIndex++] = ori.substr(startPos, strLength);
        startPos = ori.find(deli, startPos) + 1;
    }while(ori.find(deli, startPos) != string::npos);
    tokens[curIndex] = ori.substr(startPos, ori.length() - startPos);
}
```

First, I thought passing parameter as **string tokens[]** is the way call by reference, so when function is finished, tokens[] array will be full of tokens seperated by deli string. But when i call this function like

```
string str = "abc,def,10.2,dadd,adsf";
string* tokens;
split(str, tokens, ",");
```

after this, tokens array is completely empty. On my guess, this happens because of the line

```
tokens = new string[length];
```

I think memory space for tokens array as local variable is allocated and when split function is finished, this memory space will be free as block is finished.

when i try to debug, split function itself is working very well as tokens array is full of tokens at least in split function block. I think my guess is right but how can I solve this problem? Any solution? I think this is not only matter of std::string array, this is homework of "call by reference".

**Requirement**

1. pass std::string[] type to function parameter (return tokens[] is OK too. But I think this will have same problem)
2. when function is finished, array must full of tokens
3. tokens array length must be calculated in split function(if user has to calculate tokens length, it is foolish function). Because of this, memory for tokens array can't be allocated before split function call.

Thank you in advanced for your great answer!

Comment: Nothing is passed by reference unless the parameter is a reference (with &).

Comment: I see.... so what should I do? Actually, I tried to use & but it gives a lot of error and I gave up. Not like primitive type array, size of a cell for string array is not fixed like 4 bytes. I think this is somehow problem. I think I'm really noob for C++. I used many kind of language such as C#, Java, AS3, Lua, Python etc. but I really can't use C++ well.. it's so complicated

Comment: I'd probably just return a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of forcing an out parameter and no return value.

Comment: Is it possible? if I return std::vector<std::string>, I have to allocate memory for std::vector<std::string> variable in split function block, and when I return it, isn't this variable be free? Because this variable memory space is allocated in local block..???

Comment: C++ arrays do not work like Java arrays. They are inherited from C and they do not play nice. Use vectors which, although the syntax is more different, function much more like arrays in other languages. Remember C++ defaults to passing parameters as copies (although C-style arrays, being evil, don't conform to this rule)

Comment: Create local variable `std::vector<std::string> tokens;` and use `push_back` or `resize` functions on it, and return it from the function by value. It will just work. No `new` means no problems! In C++, `new` is bad.

Answer (score 2):

As @chris suggested, something like the following code should work.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& delimiter, const std::string& str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::size_t prevPos = 0;
    while (prevPos != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::size_t currPos = str.find(delimiter, prevPos);
        result.push_back(str.substr(prevPos, currPos - prevPos));

        prevPos = currPos;

        if (prevPos != std::string::npos)
        {
            // Skip the delimiter
            prevPos += delimiter.size();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("this,is,a,test");
    std::vector<std::string> splitResult = split(",", str);
    for (const auto &s : splitResult)
    {
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    str = "this - is - a - test";
    splitResult = split(" - ", str);
    for (const auto &s : splitResult)
    {
        std::cout << "'" << s << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

```
'this'
'is'
'a'
'test'

'this'
'is'
'a'
'test'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. C++ makes me crazy... but CODING WORLD, When I go deeper and deeper, I think eventually C++ is neccessary..